# Priority on Translation Loader

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-translator

I use 2 different loader for symfony translations :

- Yaml basic loader (already implemented).
- A custom loader who save translations into a db table.

The first loader is for developer purpose (having a translation when the code is displayed in localhost without having to maintain a db).
The second is for the stage / production env. Basically, POs are using this solution and developers don't have to trigger all the CI/CD process for just change one or two translations.

So, we have the same keys into the two loaders. I want the database Loader to be displayed in priority if the translation key exists in the table, else the yaml Loader take the lead.

Unfortunately, I can display database translation for some keys but, since I have multiple yaml files for the translation, some of them are not overwritten.

Is it possible in Symfony 4 to set a default Loader, or to define priorities ? If yes, how ?

If no, can we easely force the loading of all translation files in a certain order to be sure that the last file loading is the db file ?

Comment: Added an answer, please check

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not documented, but the loaders are loaded in ascending order of the extension (or alias). So if database loader uses `.xen` as extension, it will be loaded after `.php` files but before `.xml` or `.yaml` files.

For your use case, I'd suggest to use `.zzz` (or similar) as file extension (as alias of database translations loader).

We did the same a couple of years ago and it has been working since in production.

For testing, you can register two array loaders with different alias (`xen` and `zen`) and confirm that `zen` loader overrides translations from `xen` loader.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple possibilities:

- your custom loader can have a [priority](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#tagged-services-with-priority) (higher means it called earlier). When your DB service should be last, set it to a negative number:

  ```yaml
  # config/services.yaml
  services:
    App\CustomTranslator:
      tags:
         - { name: 'translation.loader', priority: -100 }
  ```
- Implement a new [service that decorates](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container/service_decoration.html) the `\Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface` service. Within this new service, override `doLoadCatalogue`. This function is responsible for loading all data from the configured loaders. In the overridden function you can customize the logic completely.